# How to get payer email after a success payment with Paypal API (Laravel paypal/rest-api-sdk-php)?

Tags: laravel, paypal, sdk

I'm using the Paypal API with Laravel, everything works fine. I just need to find the way to get the user email address and name.

```
$payment = Payment::get($payment_id, $this->_api_context);    
$execution = new PaymentExecution();    
$execution->setPayerId( $request->query('PayerID') );
$result = $payment->execute($execution, $this->_api_context);    
if ($result->getState() == 'approved') {
   // I should get the info about the payer here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: As of 2023 there are no supported SDKs, instead use a direct HTTPS integration to first obtain an access token and then perform whichever API call. Do not use v1/payments.

---

The v1/payments PayPal-PHP-SDK is deprecated, you should not use it for any new integration.

The current supported SDK is the v2/checkout/orders Checkout-PHP-SDK, which you should use instead.

You can try the srmklive package "v3" if you like, otherwise integrate directly.

You should be able to create two routes, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls).  These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

The capture order response may have details about the payer and payment, if not use can do a 'Get' API call on the order ID for this information. Store it in your database before returning the JSON to the client code.